# #pragma omp critical VS CPU 100% usage

Tags: iphone

i have wrote a program with open-mp in visual studio 2012 and i have some problem.this is my code:

```
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(4) private(k) 
         {

    #pragma omp   for
    for(k=0x20AC6E12AF3E4DB0;k<=MAXINT64;k++)
        {
     U.k=k;
     init();
    Decrypt(s1);
    Decrypt(s2);
        }
        }
```

above code compiled and my cpu usage was 100% but output was wrong .when i change code to this:

```
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(4) private(k) 
       {    
    #pragma omp   for
    for(k=0x20AC6E12AF3E4DB0;k<=MAXINT64;k++)
       {
    U.k=k;
    init();
           #pragma omp critical
       {
    Decrypt(s1);
    Decrypt(s2);
       }
       }
       }
```

outputs become correct but in this case my cpu usage is not 100% and i lost parallelism actually!
what can i do?

Comment: iPhone? Visual Studio? Huh?

Answer (score 0):

Your program does not state what s1 and s2 are, and what init() modifies. In any case, you need to make sure one thread does not change the data that another thread uses.

"#pragma omp critical" is a bottleneck by definition, as it makes that the block can only be entered by one thread at a time.

One "#pragma omp parallel for" should be enough. Let the threads make a copy of modified variables in the for loop.